# Why is sed matching minimum and not maximum string?

Tags: regex, sed, terminal

I am trying to extract the numbers (`0.000500`) from a bunch of files alá `eta_x2-0.000500`. 
I would think that below line would do that, but i get only `0` and not `0.000500`.

How can I get the maximum match?

```
find eta* | sed 's/.*\([0-9.]\+\)/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*` is greedy, so it is going to match as many characters as possible.  In this case the `.*` will match `eta_x2-0.00050` with just the final `0` matched in your group.

Normally the answer here would be to just use a non-greedy match using `.*?`, but I don't think sed supports that.

You should be able to get this to work by requiring that there is one non-digit character before you start matching, this way the `.*` will have to stop before consuming the digits:

```
sed 's/.*[^0-9.]\([0-9.]\+\)/\1/g'
```

Of course if you know the digits you want will be immediately after a `-`, you can replace `[^0-9.]` with `-` and it will work the same way.

Comment: Thanks F.J. I was so focused on the end part and why that did not seem to act greedy, I forgot about the first. The notion led me to searching for greedyness in sed. It turns out, what I was probably looking for was `perl`, which does support non-greedy modifier, and as a bonus doesn't require as much \escaping. Also, perl has useful shorthands like \d and \w. So with that I can get: `find eta* | perl -pe 's|.*?(\d+\.\d+)|\1|'`. With [this](http://nixtip.wordpress.com/2011/06/14/text-processing-performance-perl-vs-sed/), sed and perl seem to be equally fast. So why would anybody still use sed?

Answer (score 1):

add `-` in sed before the last numbers, and g is useless.

```
find eta* | sed  's/.*-\([0-9.]\+\)/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need sed

```
find eta* | grep -oP '(?<=-)[\s.]+'
find eta* | cut -d'-' -f 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

```
find eta* | sed 's/[^-]*-\([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\)/\1/'
```